# SQL - Counting rows based on specific digit value in a field

Tags: sql, oracle, count

I am using Oracle database.

In my table t_mytable, I have one field myfield and this field has string values like 00101110010.

I need to count the rows which has ""4th digit of myfield value is 1".

For instance,

```
myfield
-------
00101110010
00111110010
00101101010
00101110010
00111111110
```

For above data, count should be 2 because 2 rows has fourth bit as 1 (I started from 1 not 0 while determining first digit).

How can I do this in sql?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Oh sorry, I missed the most basic information, it is Oracle.

Comment: And please show us the code that you are having issues with

Comment: Hint:  `SUBSTR()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if myfield is a string  you can use substr for extract the fourth char

```
select count(*)
from t_mytable
where substr(myfield, 4,1) ='1';
```

Comment: @UgurKAYA   .  looking to  your questions in your profile  seem that you don't mark as accepted  the question you post ... this is not fair  .. the communty help  and you should  recognize the correct  help t that you received

Comment: Sorry I was just late.